# how to get autocompleted lat long values in ng-model in angularjs and save to mongodb using mongoose

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

i have a div which is repeated for multiple pick up and drop locations.

index.html

```
<div class="pickUpLocationSection" ng-repeat="pickUp in pickUpItems">
<div class="pick" id="pick1">
    <div class="form-group pickup" id="pickup1">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fleet-type">Pickup Location</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="search-query form-control placepicker" placeholder="Enter Location" id="pickUpLocation" data-latitude-input="#latitudePick_1" ng-model="pickUp.pickUpLocation_1" data-longitude-input="#longitudePick_1" />
                    <!-- <input type="hidden" class="pickPlace" ng-model="pickPlace_1" id="pickPlace_1" /> -->
                    <input type="text" class="latPick" id="latitudePick_1" ng-model="pickUp.latitudePick_1" />
                    <input type="text" class="longPick" id="longitudePick_1" ng-model="pickUp.longitudePick_1" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                                            <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="customer-name"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-2 border-dotted">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="pickUp.pickUpDatepicker_1" class="form-control pickUpDatepicker_1">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 p-l-0 border-dotted">
            <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                <input type="text" ng-model="pickUp.pickUpTimePicker_1" class="form-control input-small pickUpTimePicker">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 p-l-0 border-dotted">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12 p-l-0">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="pickUp.pickUpDescription_1" class="pickUpDescription_1  search-query form-control" placeholder="Description" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 p-l-0 border-dotted pick_div">
            <span class="pick_span"><a class="btn btn-success addMorePickUpLocations" ng-click="addMorePickUpLocations()" id="1"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It repeats using the controller code

```
$scope.pickUpItems = [{pickUpLocation_1: '', latitudePick_1: '', longitudePick_1:'', pickUpDatepicker_1:'' , pickUpTimePicker_1: '', pickUpDescription_1:''}];
$(".placepicker").placepicker();
$scope.addMorePickUpLocations = function(){
    $(".placepicker").placepicker();
    $scope.pickUpItems.push({
        pickUpLocation_1:"",
        latitudePick_1:"",
        longitudePick_1:"",
        pickUpDatepicker_1:"",
        pickUpTimePicker_1:"",
        pickUpDescription_1:""
    });
};
```

But on autocomplete of the search for pick up locations the latitude and longitude will display in the hidden text boxes but are not being fetched by the ng-model. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Html code for save:

<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="submit(pickUpItems)">Create Fleet</button>


Code in my controller:

var fleetData = {};
    $scope.submit = function() {  
  console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.pickUpItems));
}

Help me repeated display values to get saved in $scope.pickUpItems

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0-rc2" data-semver="1.2.0-rc2" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation/master/dist/angularjs-geolocation.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <p>Your location is: {{coords}}</p>
</div>
```

controller code

```
angular.module('myApp',['geolocation'])
.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope,geolocation) {
$scope.coords = geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data){
  return {lat:data.coords.latitude, long:data.coords.longitude};
});
```

});

install the angular geo location

```
bower install angularjs-geolocation
```

Comment: above code to get coordinates of the current location